# For any set of formulas in propositional logic, there is an equivalent and independent set

Tags: logic, propositional-calculus

A set of formulas is independent if no proper subset is logically equivalent to it.

Note that this exercise appears in Enderton 1.2 10(c) and is marked as star.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

For an infinite $S$ we cannot stick to getting an equivalent and independent *subset* of $S$. An example that shows this is
$$ \begin{align} S =\{ & A_1 ,\\
 & A_1 \land A_2 ,\\
 & A_1 \land A_2 \land A_3 ,\\
 & A_1 \land A_2 \land A_3 \land A_4 , \ldots \} \end{align} $$
for propositional variables $A_i$. No set that contains two of these formulas is independent, and on the other hand, no singleton implies everything here.

However, let's enumerate the original set $S=\{\varphi_0,\varphi_1,\ldots,\varphi_n,\ldots\}$ (this is possible because there are only countably many possible wffs), and then consider
$$ \begin{align} T_0 =\{ & \varphi_0 ,\\
 & \varphi_0 \to \varphi_1 ,\\
 & (\varphi_0\land\varphi_1)\to\varphi_2 ,\\
 & (\varphi_0\land\varphi_1\land\varphi_2)\to\varphi_3 , \ldots \} \end{align} $$
and let $T$ consist of those formulas in $T_0$ *that are not tautologies*.

Clearly $S$ implies $T_0$ and vice versa, and $T_0$ is equivalent to $T$, so $T$ is equivalent to $S$. We must show that $T$ is independent.

Let $\psi_n \equiv (\varphi_0\land\cdots\land\varphi_{n-1})\to\varphi_n$ be an arbitrary element of $T$. We will show that $\psi_n$ is *not* implied by the other formulas in $T$.

By construction $\psi_n$ was not a tautology, so there is some valuation that makes it *false*. This is only possible if the valuation makes $\varphi_0$ upto $\varphi_{n-1}$ true (which makes all of the earlier $\psi$s true) and $\varphi_n$ false (which makes all of the *later* $\psi$s true). So this valuation is a witness that
$$ T\setminus\{\psi_n\}\cup\{\neg\psi_n\} $$
is consistent, or in other words that $\psi_n$ is not implied by the rest of $T$, Q.E.D.

Comment: very nice, this is much simpler than the proof I came up with :)

Answer (score 1):

The proof for any *finite* set of formulas is easy enough:

Assume set of formulas $S$ is not itself an independent set (if it is, then clearly $S$ meets the condition of the theorem since $S$ is obviously equivalent to itself). Let the number of formulas in $S$ be $n_0$.

Since $S$ is not an independent set, there is some proper subset $T_1 \subset S$ which is logically equivalent to $S$.  If $T_1$ is independent, then $T_1$ demonstrates that $S$ meets the condition of the formula.  Let $n_1$ be the number of formulas in $T_1$.

If $T_1$ is not independent, then again there is some proper subset $T_2 \subset T_1 \subset S$ which is logically equivalent to $T_1$.  Since $T_2 \subset S$, if $T_2$ is independent, then $T_2$ demonstrates that $S$ meets the condition of the formula. If not, let $n_2$ be the number of formulas in $T_2$.  Since $T_2$ is a proper subset, $n_2 < n_1$.

This reasoning repeats for any non-empty $T_i$.  So if $S$ does not meet the
condition  of the theorem, the sequence $\left\{ n_i \right\}$ is a sequence of decreasing non-negative integers of arbitrary length, starting from the finite $n_0$.  Such a sequence does not exist, so $S$ meets the condition of the theorem.

The problem is much more difficult if we allow for infinte sets of formulas.

Comment: Thanks, Mark. In fact the whole point of this problem is to prove the statement for infinite sets.