# For any uncountable set of formulas in propositional logic, is there is an equivalent and independent set of prositions?

Tags: logic, propositional-calculus

Suppose I relax the restriction of propositional logic, allowing the primitive propositions to be uncountable. Does it follow that every set of propositions has an independent set equivalent to it? The countable case is covered here:

[For any set of formulas in propositional logic, there is an equivalent and independent set](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/987997/for-any-set-of-formulas-in-propositional-logic-there-is-an-equivalent-and-indep)

What happens in the general case?

Comment: What exactly is your language? Do you allow for uncountable disjunctions and conjunctions?

Comment: Nope, only syntactic implication with standard three axioms and modus ponens.

Comment: Do you mean that you are allowing for an uncountable number of propositional variables?  (And consequently, it is possible to have an uncountable number of propositional expressions?)

Comment: Yep, I think that link from Andres solves it.